# Why this sql query keeps showing me a syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

The syntax error showed at "as t3" in the following code.
Im trying to full outer join 2 tables, but since mysql does not have full join, im using union to union 2 left/right joined table. 
To me, I can not find any syntax error what so ever, but it just wont work...

```
SELECT 
    name, f.author_nameauthor_id, c1, c2 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
          author_id, c1, c2 
    FROM 
    (
        (SELECT 
               author_id, amount AS c1 
         FROM Author_Keyword_Count 
         WHERE keyword_id=19478) AS t1 

         LEFT OUTER JOIN 

        (SELECT 
               author_id, amount AS c2 
         FROM Author_Keyword_Count 
         WHERE keyword_id=33944) AS t2 

         ON author_id=author_id
    ) 
    UNION 
    (
        (SELECT author_id, amount AS c1 FROM Author_Keyword_Count WHERE keyword_id=19478) AS t3 
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT author_id, amount AS c2 FROM Author_Keyword_Count WHERE keyword_id=33944) AS t4 
         ON author_id=author_id
    )
) AS f 

LEFT OUTER JOIN Author ON author_id=id;
```

Comment: Why are you giving your subqueries aliases then not using them to reference their columns?

Comment: I think the UNION is misplaced.

Comment: @marc_s jeesh man, no need to get angry.  What's the big deal?  You could have said the same thing "politely" and gotten the same message across.  How does using ??? and ! make your point any better?

Comment: If you are trying to simulate a cross join, you probably want union all.

Comment: @marc_s I did specify in the tag

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Comment: Reformatted your query to show the nesting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations included below...

```
SELECT name
     , f.author_nameauthor_id
     , c1
     , c2 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT author_id
            , c1
            , c2 
         FROM 
            (   !-- <-- something missing here!?!
                  ( SELECT author_id
                         , amount c1 
                      FROM Author_Keyword_Count 
                     WHERE keyword_id = 19478
                  ) t1 
               LEFT
               JOIN
                  ( SELECT author_id
                         , amount c2 
                      FROM Author_Keyword_Count 
                     WHERE keyword_id = 33944
                  ) t2 
                 ON author_id = author_id !-- <-- which author id equals which other author id!?!? 
            ) 
        UNION 
            (  !-- <-- something missing here!?!?
                ( SELECT author_id
                       , amount c1 
                    FROM Author_Keyword_Count 
                   WHERE keyword_id = 19478
                ) t3 
            RIGHT 
             JOIN  !-- for ease of conceptualising, consider restructuring your logic to use a LEFT JOIN instead of a RIGHT JOIN
                ( SELECT author_id
                       , amount c2 
                    FROM Author_Keyword_Count 
                   WHERE keyword_id = 33944
                ) t4 
               ON author_id = author_id !-- <-- which author id equals which other author id!?!?  
            )
      ) f 
   LEFT
   JOIN Author 
     ON author_id = id;  !-- <-- which author id equals which id!?!?
```

Conceptally, you've written `(SELECT 'x') a JOIN (SELECT 'y') b` which is (*I think*) invalid. You could instead write `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'x') a JOIN (SELECT 'y') b`, but perhaps there's a more elegant way structuring this query - if only we knew what you were actually trying to do.

Comment: You need aliases on your join columns. `Ex:t.author_id = t1.author_id`

Comment: @rs They're not *my* columns! ;-)